# How would I check if user input is over the Int limit using public static main void (String args[])

Tags: java, int

This is what I've put so far:

```
public class CheckNum {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(args[i]) > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                System.out.println("Input value is too big");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

However when I do put in a digit in linux thats over the Integer Max Value like this:

java CheckNum 1234567890

I get a NumberFormats error at parseInt, which I'm guessing is from the inability to convert the too large number into an Integer even before comparing with the max value of Integer. Is there another way to check if the number entered is too large for an integer using just the inputs on String args[]?

Comment: `try - catch(NumberFormatException)` ? `args` is a `String[]`, so this is up to you to check the values you want to parse. This has nothing to do with the fact that it came from the cmd. You could use `String s = "1234567890";` then parse it, it is the same.

Comment: It worked! Thank You!

Comment: You woudn't. Whether the check is in `public static void main(String[] args)` or elsewhere is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @okbuthow if this is answering your problem, I have posted the solution in an answer, don't forget to accept the solution (if it helps of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply catch the exception you get

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        try{
            Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.format("Input %d is incorrect : %s%n", i, args[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

It will print the input index that are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can either catch the exception as suggested by @AxelH or try below suggestion

You may cast the input to Long and then check if the value is greater than max value of Integer or not.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Long l = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
        if(l > Integer.MAX_VALUE){
            System.out.println("Value can't be handled by Integer");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Proper Integer");
        }

    }
```

Please note you may still get NumberFormatException if the input can't be parsed to Long.

And if the input can go larger then use `BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(args[0]);`

If you want to get details on how to operate on BigInteger 
Refer to documentation of BigInteger [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiTmOKG5MLXAhWLDMAKHfryAd4QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Fmath%2FBigInteger.html&usg=AOvVaw3l7Dx1z11tgycMgK6K8FqE)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an exception to validate that the user has entered a wrong value. Knowing what exactly is the problem is a bit harder because it can be caused from many things. The easiest (and best solution) would be to make it like:

```
try {
  int result=Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
} catch (NumberFormatException e){
   System.out.println("Input value is not an integer [-2147483648 : 2147483647 ]");
}
```

If you insist on knowing the problem you need to do additional checks. But you will need to use the arg[0] as a string and do some string manipulation. Like for example if you try to cast it to long it might be bigger even than a long. Or it might contain a letter or even something like @#$@$^!@T!@$^. So you need to check if it contains just numbers, check if it is floating point value, try casting it to BigInteger for example. But all these tests are meaningless because they still lead to the same problem - wrong input :)